# Can I build a graphical interface from ocaml toplevel?

Tags: functional-programming, gtk, ocaml, read-eval-print-loop, ml

À few questions regarding the interactive toplevel and graphical UI programming:

1. Is it possible to build a graphical interface dynamically from ocaml toplevel?
2. It is possible to use the Graphics library too?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. You can use the LWT toplevel with integration with the lablgtk main loop:

install lwt-glib and lablgtk, on debian based systems:

apt-get install liblwt-glib-ocaml-dev liblablgtk2-ocaml-dev

in the OCaml toplevel, load everything:

```
#use "topfind";;
#require "lwt.simple-top";;
#require "lwt.glib";;
#require "lablgtk2";;
```

then initialise the GTK and the LWT integration:

```
GMain.init ();;
Lwt_glib.install ();;
```

And play:

```
let w = GWindow.window ();;
w#show ();;
```

2. Graphics does not have a main loop like GTK, so there is no problem there. But inside a GTK application you should use cairo instead.

Comment: That's wonderful. I had been looking for such a trick for so long !

Comment: It is possible to use the Graphics library too ?

Comment: Graphics does not have a main loop like GTK, so there is no problem there. But inside a GTK application you should use cairo instead.

Comment: Is there a module with Graphics interface to play with Cairo ?

Comment: There is actually a binding for Cairo library in OCaml, check [ocaml-cairo](http://caml.inria.fr/cgi-bin/hump.en.cgi?contrib=518).

Answer (score 6):

You can also use the `Graphics` module (see the [manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Graphics.html)). You will need to manage a lot of things yourself  (the event loop, the toolkits) but it is much simpler than `lablgtk`:

```
#load "graphics.cma";;
Graphics.open_graph " ";;
```